# Informatica Cobol file with more than two 01-level groups

Tags: cobol, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using COBOL file as source where 01 level groups are two. Following are the details.

In Output file first and last row are required and middle two rows are extra. Am I missing any setting or there is some other error.

**Input data File:**

```
2014001100450005000000001141107TD2798600000200120011201400090029+000000000024850+000000000000000+000000000000000000CATALOG    SCTEST TEST                     12 MAIN ST                         HINGHAM                  MA 020430000111-111-111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000001        0000 00000002786354800000000000000064486448
2015001000440007123456789123456789ABCD301088+123456789+1234567891234123456789ABCDEZZ1234ABCD12341234567890ABCDEFBCD1234567890ABCDEF12341234
```

**OutPut file:**

```
2014,11,45,5,2014001,100450005,1,141107TD27986,14,1107T,D27986,141107,TD,279,86,000,002,12,11,2014,9,29,248.50,0.00,0.000000000,CATALOG, , ,  ,SC,TEST TEST ,                    ,12 MAIN ST                         ,HINGHAM                  ,MA ,020430000,2043,0,020430,000,111-111-1111,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,1,        ,0, ,27863548,0,6448,6448
,2014,11,45,5,2014001,100450005,1,141107TD27986,14,1107T,D27986,141107,TD,279,86,000,002,120011.20,14000900.29,0,24,24,24,24,24,850+0,0,0,00000000,0,+000000000000000,000CATALOG    SCTES,,
2015,10,44,7,2015001,440007,123456789,123456789ABCD,12,34567,89ABCD,123456,78,9AB,CD,301,088,123,4567,8901,2345,6789,,,,1234567,8,9,0A,BC,DEF1234123,4,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
2015,10,44,7,2015001,440007,123456789,123456789ABCD,12,34567,89ABCD,123456,78,9AB,CD,301,088,1234567.89,1234567.89,1234,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,ABCDE,Z,Z,1234ABCD,1234,1234567890ABCDEF,BCD1234567890ABCDEF,1234,1234
```

**Desired Output:**

```
2014,11,45,5,2014001,100450005,1,141107TD27986,14,1107T,D27986,141107,TD,279,86,000,002,12,11,2014,9,29,248.50,0.00,0.000000000,CATALOG, , ,  ,SC,TEST TEST ,                    ,12 MAIN ST                         ,HINGHAM                  ,MA ,020430000,2043,0,020430,000,111-111-1111,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,1,        ,0, ,27863548,0,6448,6448
2015,10,44,7,2015001,440007,123456789,123456789ABCD,12,34567,89ABCD,123456,78,9AB,CD,301,088,1234567.89,1234567.89,1234,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,123456789,ABCDE,Z,Z,1234ABCD,1234,1234567890ABCDEF,BCD1234567890ABCDEF,1234,1234
```

**Source File:**

```
        environment division.
        select SAHDR-SAADMIN assign to "fname".
        data division.
        file section.
        fd  SAHDR-SAADMIN.
        01  STSHDR-RECORD.
        05  SAHDR-KEY.
        10  SAHDR-FISCAL-POSTING-DATE.
            15  SAHDR-FISCAL-YEAR            PIC  9(04).
            15  SAHDR-FISCAL-MONTH           PIC  9(04).
            15  SAHDR-FISCAL-WEEK            PIC  9(04).
            15  SAHDR-FISCAL-DAY             PIC  9(04).
        10  SAHDR-RELATIVE-DATE
                REDEFINES SAHDR-FISCAL-POSTING-DATE.
            15  SAHDR-DAY-IDNT               PIC  9(07).
            15  SAHDR-FILLER                 PIC  9(09).
        10  SAHDR-STORE-NUMBER               PIC  9(09).
        10  SAHDR-TRANSACTION-NUMBER-KEY     PIC  X(13).
        10  SAHDR-TRANSACTION-NUMBER
                REDEFINES SAHDR-TRANSACTION-NUMBER-KEY.
            15  SAHDR-REGISTER-NUMBER        PIC  X(02).
            15  SAHDR-TRANS-NUMBER           PIC  X(05).
            15  SAHDR-TRANS-SORT             PIC  X(06).
        10  SAHDR-MO-TRANS-NUMBER
                REDEFINES SAHDR-TRANSACTION-NUMBER-KEY.
            15  SAHDR-MO-ORDER-DATE          PIC  X(06).
            15  SAHDR-MO-DEPT-CLERK          PIC  X(02).
            15  SAHDR-MO-ORDER-BATCH         PIC  X(03).
            15  SAHDR-MO-ORDER-SEQ-NUMBER    PIC  X(02).
        10  SAHDR-RECORD-TYPE                PIC  X(03).
            88  SAHDR-HEADER-RECORD            VALUE '000'.
        10  SAHDR-TRANS-TYPE                 PIC  X(03).
            88  SAHDR-SALE-TRANSACTION         VALUE '001'.
        05  SAHDR-DATA.
        10  SAHDR-TRANSACTION-DATE.
            15  SAHDR-CALENDAR-MONTH         PIC  9(04).
            15  SAHDR-CALENDAR-DAY           PIC  9(04).
            15  SAHDR-CALENDAR-YEAR          PIC  9(04).
        10  SAHDR-TRANSACTION-TIME.
            15  SAHDR-REG-TRANS-HOUR         PIC  9(04).
            15  SAHDR-REG-TRANS-MINUTE       PIC  9(04).
        10  SAHDR-TOTAL-TRANS-AMOUNT         PIC +9(13)V99.
        10  SAHDR-CONVERSION-TRANS-AMOUNT    PIC +9(13)V99.
        10  SAHDR-CONVERSION-RATE            PIC +9(09)V9(9).
        10  SAHDR-TRANS-ORIGIN               PIC  X(07).
            88  SAHDR-POINT-OF-SALE            VALUE 'POS    '.
            88  SAHDR-MAILORDER                VALUE 'CATALOG'.
        10  SAHDR-TRANS-VOID-DURING-FLAG     PIC  X(01).
        10  SAHDR-TRANS-POST-VOID-FLAG       PIC  X(01).
        10  SAHDR-TRANS-ERROR-CODE           PIC  X(02).
            88  SAHDR-NO-ERRORS                VALUE '00'.
        10  SAHDR-RFS-LOCATION-TYPE          PIC  X(02).
        10  SAHDR-CUSTOMER-NAME.
            15  SAHDR-CUSTOMER-FNAME         PIC  X(10).
            15  SAHDR-CUSTOMER-LNAME         PIC  X(20).
        10  SAHDR-CUSTOMER-ADDRESS           PIC  X(35).
        10  SAHDR-CUSTOMER-CITY              PIC  X(25).
        10  SAHDR-CUSTOMER-STATE             PIC  X(03).
        10  SAHDR-CUSTOMER-ZIPCODE           PIC  X(09).
        10  SAHDR-USA-ZIPCODE
                REDEFINES SAHDR-CUSTOMER-ZIPCODE.
            15  SAHDR-CUSTOMER-FIRST-FIVE    PIC  9(05).
            15  SAHDR-CUSTOMER-LAST-FOUR     PIC  9(04).
        10  SAHDR-CANADA-ZIPCODE
                REDEFINES SAHDR-CUSTOMER-ZIPCODE.
            15  SAHDR-CANADA-CUST-ZIP        PIC  X(06).
            15  FILLER                       PIC  X(03).
        10  SAHDR-CUSTOMER-PHONE             PIC  X(12).
        10  SAHDR-SALESPERSON.
            15  SAHDR-CASHIER                PIC  9(07).
            15  SAHDR-HEADER-SALESPERSON     PIC  9(07).
        10  SAHDR-EMPLOYEE-SELLING-NUMBER    PIC  9(09).
        10  SAHDR-EMPLOYEE-PURCHASE-NUMBER   PIC  9(09).
        10  SAHDR-SHIPPING-RECORD-NUMBER     PIC  9(09).
        10  SAHDR-ADMIN-COUNTER              PIC  9(04).
        10  SAHDR-ITEM-COUNTER               PIC  9(04).
        10  SAHDR-REGTOT-COUNTER             PIC  9(04).
        10  SAHDR-STRTOT-COUNTER             PIC  9(04).
        10  SAHDR-TAXRCD-COUNTER             PIC  9(04).
        10  SAHDR-TENDER-COUNTER             PIC  9(04).
        10  SAHDR-USERID                     PIC  X(08).
        10  SAHDR-EMP-DEPT                   PIC  9(04).
        10  SAHDR-ERROR-CODE                 PIC  X(01).
        10  SAHDR-CUSTOMER-ID                PIC  9(15).
        10  SAHDR-LOYALTY-ID                 PIC  9(15).
        10  SAHDR-TRANS-TIME.
            15  SAHDR-REG-TRANS-HR           PIC  9(04).
            15  SAHDR-REG-TRANS-MIN          PIC  9(04).
        01  STSADMIN-RECORD.
        05  SAADMIN-KEY.
        10  SAADMIN-FISCAL-POSTING-DATE.
            15  SAADMIN-FISCAL-YEAR          PIC  9(04).
            15  SAADMIN-FISCAL-MONTH         PIC  9(04).
            15  SAADMIN-FISCAL-WEEK          PIC  9(04).
            15  SAADMIN-FISCAL-DAY           PIC  9(04).
        10  SAADMIN-RELATIVE-DATE
                REDEFINES SAADMIN-FISCAL-POSTING-DATE.
            15  SAADMIN-DAY-IDNT             PIC  9(07).
            15  SAADMIN-FILLER               PIC  9(09).
        10  SAADMIN-STORE-NUMBER             PIC  9(09).
        10  SAADMIN-TRANSACTION-NUMBER-KEY   PIC  X(13).
        10  SAADMIN-TRANSACTION-NUMBER
                REDEFINES SAADMIN-TRANSACTION-NUMBER-KEY.
            15  SAADMIN-REGISTER-NUMBER      PIC  X(02).
            15  SAADMIN-TRANS-NUMBER         PIC  X(05).
            15  SAADMIN-TRANS-SORT           PIC  X(06).
        10  SAADMIN-MO-TRANSACTION-NUMBER
                REDEFINES SAADMIN-TRANSACTION-NUMBER-KEY.
            15  SAADMIN-MO-ORDER-DATE        PIC  X(06).
            15  SAADMIN-MO-DEPT-CLERK        PIC  X(02).
            15  SAADMIN-MO-ORDER-BATCH       PIC  X(03).
            15  SAADMIN-MO-ORDER-SEQ-NUMBER  PIC  X(02).
        10  SAADMIN-RECORD-TYPE              PIC  X(03).
            88  SAADMIN-ADMINISTRATIVE         VALUE '301'.
        10  SAADMIN-TRANSACTION-TYPE         PIC  X(03).
            88  SAADMIN-POST-VOID              VALUE '088'.
        05  SAADMIN-DATA.
        10  SAADMIN-AMOUNT                   PIC +9(07)V99.
        10  SAADMIN-CONVERSION-AMOUNT        PIC +9(07)V99.
        10  SAADMIN-POS-EXPENSE-NUMBER       PIC  9(04).
        10  SAADMIN-TRANS-ID-NUMBER          PIC  9(09).
        10  SAADMIN-CHARGE-ACCOUNT-NUMBER      REDEFINES
            SAADMIN-TRANS-ID-NUMBER          PIC  9(09).
        10  SAADMIN-GIFT-CERTIFICATE           REDEFINES
            SAADMIN-TRANS-ID-NUMBER          PIC  9(09).
        10  SAADMIN-MDSE-CREDIT-NUMBER         REDEFINES
            SAADMIN-TRANS-ID-NUMBER          PIC  9(09).
        10  SAADMIN-COUPON-NUMBER              REDEFINES
            SAADMIN-TRANS-ID-NUMBER          PIC  9(09).
        10  SAADMIN-ORIGINAL-TRAN-NUMBER     PIC  X(05).
        10  SAADMIN-VOID-DURING-FLAG         PIC  X(01).
        10  SAADMIN-POST-VOID-FLAG           PIC  X(01).
        10  SAADMIN-USERID                   PIC  X(08).
        10  SAADMIN-EMP-DEPT                 PIC  9(04).
        10  SAADMIN-GIFT-CARD-NUMBER         PIC  X(16).
        10  SAADMIN-TOKEN-NUMBER             PIC  X(19).
        10  SAADMIN-TRANS-TIME.
            15  SAADMIN-REG-TRANS-HR         PIC  9(04).
            15  SAADMIN-REG-TRANS-MIN        PIC  9(04).
        working-storage section.
        procedure division.
        stop run.
```

Comment: It's probably the code you have, which you need to show. On it's own the file-layout doesn't tell much.

Comment: I am just writing normalized data to flat file. Which i showed in out put file. No property is set in that.

Comment: Unless you just waved your magic wand and mumbled "Normalize", there was something you did. It looks like whatever you did is applying each 01-level to each input record and outputting two records for each input record. In whatever you did in place of the wand-waving, you have to create a mapping of record-type to 01-level. This will probably involve `SAADMIN-RECORD-TYPE` and `SAADMIN-TRANSACTION-TYPE`

Answer (score 0):

Just do not use the ports from SAADMIN-FISCAL-YEAR to the end. What I understand, the statement "01  STSADMIN-RECORD." starts a new record using the same data. So, to get your desired output, propagate the ports for the first record (01  STSHDR-RECORD) only, which is up to SAHDR-REG-TRANS-MIN